# Convergence in $\overline A $ of a limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $X$ be a metric space, $A\subset X$ and $\phi_n$ a sequence of continuous bounded functions in $X$ converging pointwise to $f$, uniformly in $A$. My question is: how can I show that they converge uniformly to $f$ also in $\overline A$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the $\phi_n$ are all continuous, we have

$$\sup \{ \lvert \phi_n(x) - \phi_k(x)\rvert : x \in \overline{A}\} = \underbrace{\sup \{ \lvert \phi_n(x) - \phi_k(x)\rvert : x \in A\}}_s,$$

since

$$A \subset (\lvert \phi_n - \phi_k\rvert)^{-1}([0,s]),$$

and the set on the right is closed by continuity of $x \mapsto \lvert \phi_n(x) - \phi_k(x)\rvert$.

Thus the sequence $(\phi_n)$ converges uniformly to some limit $g$ on $\overline{A}$. Since $\phi_n$ by assumption converges to $f$ pointwise on $X$, it follows that $g = f\lvert_{\overline{A}}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; just one more question: I've not so clear why $\phi_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $\overline A$.

Comment: The restrictions $\phi_n\lvert_{\overline{A}}$ form a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d(\phi,\psi) = \sup \{ \lvert\phi(x) - \psi(x)\rvert : x \in \overline{A}\}$. So, given $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $n(\varepsilon)$ such that $\lvert \phi_n(x) - \phi_k(x)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n,k \geqslant n(\varepsilon)$ and $x\in \overline{A}$. Keep $n$ fixed and let $k\to\infty$ to see that $\lvert \phi_n(x) - \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \phi_k(x)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n \geqslant n(\varepsilon)$ and $x\in \overline{A}$.

Comment: And that just means that $(\phi_n)$ converges uniformly to its pointwise limit on $\overline{A}$.